# Best practices for binding MVC model to WCF service through "datamodule"?

Tags: wcf, model-view-controller, model-binding, datamodule

I'm somewhat of a noob, so bear with me please.

I'm building an MVC project that gets data from a web service (WCF) as exposed by a "datamodule" class that passes parameters to the service. Right now what I have is a viewmodel that looks like this:

```
public String FirstName { get; set; }
public String LastName { get; set; }
public String DisplayName { get; set; }
public String Role { get; set; }
```

A "datamodule" class that looks like this:

```
private readonly ServiceClient _serviceClient = new ServiceClient();
public List<Info> GetStuff(int Id)
    {
        return _serviceClient.GetStuff(Id);
    }
```

And a controller action that looks like this:

```
var dm = new DataModule();
var members = dm.GetStuff(96);
    var team = from member in members
                            select new TeamModel
                                {
                                    FirstName = member.FirstName,
                                    LastName = member.LastName,
                                    Role = member.Role,
                                    DisplayName = member.DisplayName
                                };
return PartialView(team.ToList());
```

I don't feel like it's very clean (or MVC like) to manually bind data like this in every one of my controllers. Is there a best practices way to bind data like this?